# Prolog assigning values to elements of a list

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and the problem I am dealing with is the following: Given a list of variables, I want to assign a value for each element of that list, and then check if a restriction containing some of those variables is true. This is an example of how I thought it should work:

```
predicate(L1, Restriction) :-
    foreach(member(Var,L1), Var = 1),
    Restriction.
```

But when I write in the console:

```
? - predicate([A,B,C], A==1).
```

or

```
? - predicate([A,B,C], B==1).
```

or

```
? - predicate([A,B,C], A==B).
```

they all return false.

Shouldn't `A`, `B`, and `C` be all equivalent to 1 after the foreach loop?

Comment: Do keep in mind that there isn't a concept of "assignment" in prolog. It uses "unification" instead. It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulo explained well what the problem is (+1). Maybe you should correct your code like

```
predicate(L1, Restriction) :-
    maplist(=(1), L1),
    Restriction.
```

that yields the expected output

```
?- predicate([A,B,C], A==1).
A = B, B = C, C = 1.
```

Comment: I can see how maplist gets the job done here. But what if I want to make all the elements of a list equal to the respective values of another list? Say we have L1=[A,B,C] and L2=[1,2,3]. How should I approach the implementation of the predicate so that I assign 1 to A, 2 to B and 3 to C and only then test the Restriction (which involves A,B,C)?

Comment: Use `maplist/3` instead of `maplist/2`: `maplist((=), L1, L2)`.

Comment: This indeed works. Thank you! I also noticed that just writing L1=L2 leads to the same result. I didn't imagine that what I was trying to achieve was so trivial.

Comment: Indeed. There main reason to mention the maplist predicates, however, is that you can use any relation, including your predicates. Of course, for e.g. `(=)/2` or `(==)/2` there's no point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way the `foreach/2` predicate works. The first argument works as a *generator* and the second argument works as a *test* for each solution of the generator. But the predicate creates a *conjunction* where each element is a **copy** of the second argument. Because of this copying, the variables in the generator never get instantiated (as you're instantiating the copies). This semantics can be illustrated by the following query:

```
?- foreach(member(Var, [A,B,C]), Var = 1), var(A), var(B), var(C).
true.
```

As your restriction is the `predicate/2` calls is an **equality** test and a variable is not equal to an integer, all the calls fail.

If your intention is to create a list of a given length with all elements equal to a given term, there are several ways of accomplishing it. For example, using only standard built-in predicates:

```
?- findall(1, between(1, 3, _), List).
List = [1, 1, 1].
```